# How do GIT ignore directory with only char "tilde"

Tags: git, selenium, directory, ignore, tilde

I use **Selenium** with **Protractor** and **Cucumber**, to create automated tests for my projects.
These projects are versioned on **GIT** and a particular configuration of tests files create a folder named with only char "*tilde*".

I try to modify ignore file ***.gitignore*** on root when placed this directory created with only char "*tilde*" on name, but **GIT** no ignore that directory and her files.

What I do to force **GIT** ignore directory?

Comment: What tool creates a directory of name `~`?

This is would mess up things on UNIX systems.

Comment: I think Cucumber create that directory, but not sure... otherwise Selenium...

Comment: I think **you** created that directory. I doubt any tool would do that, considering `~` is a special character. To remove it `rmdir ./\~`

Comment: Absolutely no... that directory contains profile files for Chrome used to automatize action on browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore `~` or `~/`:

```
$ git status --short 
?? ~/

$ echo \~/ >>.gitignore 

$ git status --short 
 M .gitignore
```

Comment: Not work...  
  
$ git status --short
 M ~/.e2e-chrome-profile/chrome_debug.log
$ echo \~/ >>.gitignore

$ git status --short
 M .gitignore
 M ~/.e2e-chrome-profile/chrome_debug.log

Comment: The first command shows that you've already added `~/.e2e-chrome-profile/chrome_debug.log`. `gitignore` doesn't ignore added files, it only ignores untracked files. Remove the file from git: `git rm -r --cached \~`.

Comment: WORK!  You are my boss! ;-) Thanks man! Sorry for my ignorance on use .ignore on already committed files.